# How can I calculate greatest of three numbers without using if/else or switch case in C?

Tags: c

I want to calculate greatest of given three integer numbers in C programming without using any `if`/`else` condition or `switch` case. For example in this way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int num1, num2, max;
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
    max = (num1 + num2 + abs(num1 - num2)) /2;
    printf("%d\n", max);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my code to calculate the max of given two integer numbers.

Comment: One possible way is to call your code snippet twice, once for `num1` and `num2`, then for the `max_temp` and `num3`

Comment: Why?  What problem would writing convoluted code to avoid `if/else` or `switch` statements solve?  Performance?  You don't know you have a performance issue yet, and any code you write that you think is faster than code that branches is likely to be slower than what an optimizing compiler will create from clear, understandable, simple, and maintainable code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's not about performance, I just wanted to know every different ways of solving this problem. If I just only wanted the solution there may be some answers which I already can do by myself. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the max function twice:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int num1, num2, num3, max;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
    max = (num1 + num2 + abs(num1-num2))/2;
    max = (max + num3 + abs(max-num3))/2;
    printf("%d\n", max);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are many cases where `abs(num1-num2)` has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary expression as well:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define max2(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define max3(a,b,c) max2(max2((a), (b)), (c))

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", max3(10, -10, 20));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes no sense: the meaning of `abs(x)` is (more or less):

```
int abs(int x)
{
    if (x>0) 
      return x;
    else return -x;
}
```

So the simple usage of `abs()` implies an `if`-clause.

Comment: This isn't my answer. I just wanted to know the different ways of solving this problem.

Comment: what if CPU can compute abs in hardware with no branch?

Comment: The fact you have one implementation of `abs` that uses `if` does not mean use of `abs` implies an `if` clause. The `abs` function can be implemented with bit manipulations, such as XORing the number with a repetition of its sign bit and then subtracting the sign bit.

Comment: I'm not saying that it is impossible to define `abs()` without `if` (I have learnt that `abs(x)=sqrt(x^2)`), but that was in mathematical course: no computer will perform floating point arithmetic for calculating a simple `abs()`, for performance reasons. A similar thing can be said about the `XOR` approach. By my answer, I simply wanted to show the author how a basic idea "**I use an "abs" instead of an IF**" can be wrong because "**"abs" is a kind of an IF**", which is something to consider while attacking such kind of questions.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but a comment, so it should not have been entered as an answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I see your point, but the comment boxes are too small for writing this properly.

Comment: @Dominique: That is not a justification for entering an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if`/`else` statements, you can use the ternary operator:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1, num2, num3, max;
    if (scanf("%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3) == 3) {
        max = (num1 < num2) ? num1 : num2;
        max = (max < num3) ? max : num3;
        printf("%d\n", max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the ternary operator is not allowed, you can use comparison operators, which may generate branchless code anyway:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1, num2, num3, max;
    if (scanf("%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3) == 3) {
        max = (num1 >= num2) * num1 + (num1 < num2) * num2;
        max = (max >= num2) * max + (max < num2) * num2;
        printf("%d\n", max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you cannot use `num1 + num2` nor `num1 - num2`, not even `-num1` nor `num2` because there operations may cause arithmetic overflow with undefined behavior.

Also note that you can abuse the rules by replacing `if` statements with `while` or `for` statements:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1, num2, num3;
    if (scanf("%d%d%d", &num1, &num2, &num3) == 3) {
        for (max = num1; max < num2; max = num2)
            continue;
        while (max < num3)
            max = num3;
        printf("%d\n", max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> without using any if/else condition or switch case

```
#define m(a,b,c)a>b?a>c?a:c:b>c?b:c
```

35 bytes, I win.

Comment: Why use a macro? `printf("%d\n",a>b?a>c?a:c:b>c?b:c);`

Comment: @chqrlie Because macros have more vulnerabilities, some which I intentionally exposed here. Artificial requirements deserve an artificial answer.

Answer (score -1):

You may use something similar to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a,b,c, max_num;


int maxof3(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
    return(max(max(num1, num2), num3));
}

int main()
{
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    max_num = maxof3(a, b, c);
    printf("%d\n", max_num);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `max` defined?

Answer (score -1):

Since you asked different ways, and not efficient ways you can sort them using the `qsort` library function and then return the last element.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp (const void * a, const void * b) { return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b ); }

int main (void) {
   int arr[3];
   scanf("%d %d %d", &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2]); //ignoring valid input check, assuming valid input
   qsort(arr, 3, sizeof(int), cmp);
   printf("max: %d",arr[2]);
   return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: `qsort(values, 3, sizeof(int))` is not a working call to the standard routine `qsort`.

Comment: yeah sorry i wrote it in a hurry, i fixed the code, thanks

Comment: `return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );` does not work if the numbers are too far apart: `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` for example.

Comment: Yes, but that would be a problem for even larger datatypes. So I guess this is a limitation of using qsort here.